# MarkupCore Extension: Markups are no longer editable

Tags: javascript, autodesk-viewer

I want to use the MarkupCore Extension to add some comments to my drawings.
But when I turn on the edit-mode, draw my markups and then turn it off, all the markups are disappeared when I enter the edit-mode again.

So I figured out, that I can save the markups and load them. But when I do so, the loaded markups are no longer editable.

I am thankful for any help

**EDIT:**

I entered the following commands using the webconsole:

```
extension = viewer.getExtension('...');
extension.enterEditMode();
//Now I add some markups and them
var data = extension.generateData();
extension.leaveEditMode();

//Now I enter the edit-mode again
extension.enterEditMode();
extension.loadMarkups(data, 'Layer_1');
```

And after that, I am no longer able to select the loaded markups.

Comment: can you clarify how you is this piece of your code? Or are you using a specific sample? need a reproducible sample so I can research for you. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today (August/2016), once the markup is created and you leave the edit-mode, you cannot come back and edit it again. The markups are bounded to a specific view, therefore this behavior. We're looking into make it editable in the same view, but not currently supported on [version 2.9](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.9/).